# Statistic test for comparing two regression models

Tags: statistics, regression, regression-analysis

I'm having two linear regression models as follows:
$y = a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + c$ and $y = b_1x_1 + b_2x_3 + c$.

I'm looking for a statistical test for proving which model is better. I've obtained the $R^2$ values. Please suggest a statistical test.

Also I wanted to know how to apply the Likelihood Ratio test for comparing the above models. Is that an appropriate test for the comparison?

Comment: What are the difference between the models? What are your assumptions?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming i.i.d. normal errors, comparing the likelihood of these two models would be equivalent to comparing the $R^2$ values.

What would be the null hypothesis of this test?
You might consider fitting a model containing all three covariates and separately testing the hypotheses $H_0:\beta_2=0$ and $H_0:\beta_3=0$.